# Javascript function toLocaleString not working

Tags: javascript

Following code `toLocalString` method converting to local date time but in server not able to convert

```
var utcdatetime = new Date(Date.UTC(fromYear, fromMonth - 1, fromDay)).toLocaleString();
```

output in server: Tuesday, December 12, 2021 7:00:00 PM
Out put in Local machine: ‎12‎/‎13‎/‎2021‎ ‎4‎:‎00‎:‎00‎ ‎PM.
Desired out is as as shown in the local server.

Comment: Your server time and your local machine's timezone isn't the same.

Comment: Did you tried passing the locale and options parameters to `toLocaleString` on your server side?

Comment: I tried but out put is same. t0LocaleString  not able to convert Tuesday, December 12, 2021 7:00:00 PM  to dd/mm/yyyy number format. I am passing date is like 13/12/2021

Comment: [.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) returns string with a language sensitive representation of this date. String format and timezone shift depends on locale, so local time and output format **will not** be the same among all locales. If you need to unify output, you can use external solutions like [moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment).